# doing 2D/3D tilt view like google map using cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm trying to add a 2D/3D view tilt(same as what google map has)functionality to my cesium project, but am having trouble figuring out how to do it with the provided cesium functions.

I've tried camera rotate and look functions provided by cesium. but the camera viewer.scene.camera.rotateup and rotatedown function only rotate the camera without modifying the camera's position and attitude. I've also tried using viewer.scene.camera.flyTo function but had trouble finding ways to get the right destination.

Comment: Please include what you have attempted so far and what is the specific roadblocks that you are running into.

Comment: Try holding down the middle mouse (button/wheel, push it down, don't spin it) and moving up/down.  Or, hold down left-CTRL and left-drag up/down.